# Reveal content by animating height (not hiding all content)

Tags: jquery

I want to to partially display a list and then when a button is clicked i'd like to change the class of the button and show the full list by using the full height of the div, then when the button is clicked again i'd like it to start from its initial reveal, not hide the whole thing.

HTML:

```
<section id="newsletters">
<h4><a href="#rss"></a><span>Related</span> Button</h4>
    <nav>
        <ul>
           <li>1</li>
           <li>1</li>
           <li>1</li>
           <li>1</li>
           <li>1</li>      
        </ul>
    </nav>
<a class="hide" href="#">Show / Hide
</a></section>
```

Jquery

```
 $('section#newsletters .hide').click(function() {
    $('section#newsletters nav').toggle(400);
    return false;
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to create your own toggler. Simple and straight forward:

```
var toggle = true, oldHeight = 0;

$('section#newsletters .hide').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $ele = $('section#newsletters nav');
    var toHeight = ((toggle = !toggle) ? oldHeight : 20);

    oldHeight = $ele.height();
    $ele.animate({ height: toHeight });

});
```

Where "20" is the height in pixels to toggle to when sliding up.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/QV38D/

Comment: You mean by default you want it to be hidden?

Comment: yes please.  At the moment it starts at full height, id like it to start at the initial height of say 200 or whatever.  The height it returns to.

Answer (score 1):

This discussion triggered me to find a solution for an almost identical problem.  Below is what I used stripped down to just what you need I believe.

Can use the ternary operator to set a height variable and then just use that on animate().  Can set more options for animate() I only included height.  You can use the same thing to change the show/hide text.

```
$('section#newsletters .hide').click(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
  var height = $('section#newsletters nav').height() == '[original height]' ? '[new height]' : '[original height]';
  $('section#newsletters nav').animate({height:height};
});
```

So, if for example you wanted to go from 50px to 100px and then back to 50 you'd do:

```
$('section#newsletters .hide').click(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
  var height = $('section#newsletters nav').height() == '50' ? '100' : '50';
  $('section#newsletters nav').animate({height:height};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to use `animate` and code the toggle mechanism yourself. Something along the lines of the following:

```
$("section#newsletters .hide").click(function () {
    $("section#newsletters nav").animate({ height: "100px"}, 400,
        function() { $("section#newsletters").removeClass("hide").addClass("show"); }
    );
});
$("section#newsletters .show").click(function () {
    $("section#newsletters nav").animate({ height: "1000px"}, 400,
        function() { $("section#newsletters").removeClass("show").addClass("hide"); }
    );
});
```

The `100px` and `1000px` are height of the collapsed and expanded list, respectively.

Comment: Other content is sitting above this when i click it but im guessing thats something to do with the CSS...

Comment: The expanded height may vary as well...it wont always be 1000px